# Moving Harddisk to other server

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, sata

I have a situation that required to move 3 SATA hard Disk from a Dell T100 to T350 Server. This was working 90% ok and the Windows 2008 server started fine need only install Drivers.

- HD 1Tb (Datafiles)
- HD 160gb
- HD 1TB (Hyper-V)

But one problem the HD 1Tb (Datafiles) shows unallocated.

What can this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see an assigned drivers letter? You should try to use a data recovery tool because I have a feeling that disk got corrupted during the change. Whatever you do,DO NOT create or delete a new file-system, this will seal the deal on your hope of getting the data on the disk.

You could check in event viewer if there is any event that windows prompt when the disk failed.

Maybe look in Device manager and see if every drivers are recognized.

Comment: Hello

1.) No I see no drive letter only a unallocated partition, but i know this shoud be drive D:.

2.) The event viewer dont show any signs of a problem.

Yes they are 3 Disk but one unallocated.

Comment: Try and plug that disk in another SATA port, but I think your disk is unreadable now. :( try using Microsoft active boot disk to explore the disk.